# Amazon VPC - Elastic load balancer not forwaring requests to Private Subnet instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have setup and Elastic load balancer in VPC. There is a public and private subnet. Currently the web server is in the Private subnet and there is a NAT instance in public subnet, from which the web server can be accessed.

Now when i created an Elastic Load balancer, which pointed to the web server in private subnet, the requests from ELB are not being sent to web server.

Is there any special method through which i have to configure ELB in VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly call it "special" -- you just need to make sure that your security and ACL policies, and your route tables, are all configured appropriately.  Without knowing those, it's hard to say for sure what you need to change, but I'd review those and the problem will probably make itself known.

Comment: in the security group, all traffic is allowed In/Out. in the routing tables and subnets, i can access the web server through NAT instance. what else is reqiured?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem. The issue was that ELB had to be Placed inside the PUBLIC subnet, but u had placed it in Private subnet